# How should i declare my objects in order to use the functions properly?

Tags: c++

I'd appreciate if anyone could enlighten me what is going on here: Say I declare the following:

```
class A{
public:
    friend class A1;
}

class A1{
public:
    void f(A* a) { cout<<"Base"; };
}

class B : public A{
public:
    friend class B1;
}

class B1 : public A1{
public:
    void f(B* b) { cout << "Derived"; };
}
```

When i declare my objects i do:

```
A* a;
A1* a1;
if (condition1) {
    a = new A;
    a1 = new A1;
}
else {
    a = new B;
    a1 = new B1;
}
a1 -> f(a); //outputs always 'base'
```

How can i make`a1 -> f(a)` output `B1::f()` based on `condition1`?
Note: This is a small part of my code, and the structure of the  classes has to remain the same.

Comment: The member function `f` is not `virtual` so `a1->f` will always call the function of `A1`.

Comment: The signature of the functions are different, so it doesn't matter if it's virtual or not.

Comment: You'll always only get `base::f()`'s signature deduced with your code. So what are you wondering about?

Comment: I want to know how can i get `derived::f()`'s signature based on predefined condition.

Comment: @AndreiFlorescu You need a virtual function in first place to check for upcasts.

Comment: On `a1` you can only call function that are declared for `A1` either directly or through inheritance. If that called function is `virtual` then the runtime will check if the pointer belongs to a derived class, and checks if that class overwrites the function. So my point is still true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the right call automatically done you need to have the same signature for *f* and to have it *virtual*, the *friend* are useless

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
};

class A1{
public:
    virtual void f(A* a) { cout<<"Base" << endl; };
};

class B : public A{
};

class B1 : public A1{
public:
    virtual void f(A* b) { cout << "Derived" << endl; };
};

int main(int argc, char **)
{
  A* a;
  A1* a1;

  if (argc == 1) {
    a = new A;
    a1 = new A1;
  }
  else {
    a = new B;
    a1 = new B1;
  }
  a1 -> f(a); 
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Base
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1
Derived
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

The determination of the method to call is done in case of *virtual* on the real type of the receiver, the real type of the parameters is not relevant, only the signature is taken into account

---

If you need to check the argument of *B1::f* is a *B** you can do for instance :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    virtual ~A(){}
};

class A1{
  public:
    virtual void f(A* a) { cout<<"Base" << endl; };
};

class B : public A{
  public:
    virtual ~B(){}
};

class B1 : public A1{
  public:
    virtual void f(A* b) {
      cout << "Derived, " 
        << ((dynamic_cast<B*>(b) == NULL) 
           ? "invalid call, needed a B*"
           : "valid call with a B*")
         << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **)
{
  A* a;
  A1* a1;

  switch (argc) {
  case 1:
    a = new A;
    a1 = new A1;
    break;
  case 2:
    a = new B;
    a1 = new B1;
    break;
  default:
    a = new A;
    a1 = new B1;
  }

  a1 -> f(a); 
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Base
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1
Derived, valid call with a B*
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1 2
Derived, invalid call, needed a B*
```

I added virtual destructor in A and B to be able to use `dynamic_cast`

Or if you want to go in the base case when the argument of *B1::f* is not a *B** :

```
class B1 : public A1{
  public:
    virtual void f(A* a) {
      B * b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);

      if (b == NULL)
        A1::f(a);
      else {
        cout << "Derived" << endl;
        // use of b known as a B*
      }
   }
};
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Base
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1
Derived
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1 2
Base
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Virtual functions was my first thought as well, but in my main code(this being a summery of my classes) i need the B class derived from the A class.

Comment: @AndreiFlorescu B is derived from A in my code too `class B : public A {}`

Comment: I meant, i need the B structure in my B1::f() function, because it's different from the base A.

Comment: @AndreiFlorescu I edited my answer, but you need to have the same signature in both f

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndreiFlorescu you welcome, in case I edited again to have the call you want without error